# Is there a built in way to deserialize Map<String,String> in Jackson

Tags: java, spring, jackson

API is returning array of map entries like this

```
[
{"key":"Key1","value":"Value1"},
{"key":"Key2","value":"Value2"}, 
{"key":"Key3","value":"Value3"},
....
]
```

And I would like to deserialize it directly into `Map<String,String>`
so it w will become

```
Map<String,String> {Key1->Value1, Key2->Value2, Key3->Value3}
```

Obvious solution is to deserialize as `List<ApiMapEntry>` but maybe there is an simpler way of doing so?

What I am doing now:

```
@JsonProperty
public void setMyTargetMap(List<ApiMapEntryWrapper> wrappers) {
    this.myTargetMap= wrappers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(ApiMapEntryWrapper::getKey, ApiMapEntryWrapper::getValue));
}

class ApiMapEntryWrapper{
   private String key;
   private String value;
}
```

While I would look for something like (referring to exampe json) without the need of `ApiMapEntryWrapper`

```
@JsonMap(keyName="key",valueName="value")
private Map<String,Strin> myTargetMap
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson can by default deserialize into a `Map<String, String>`. So the following should work by default.

```
@GetMapping
public void getSomething(@RequestBody Map<String,String> map) {
      ....
}
```

But your case seems different, since you expect multiple JSON objects inside a List with duplicate information of `key`: `somekey`, `value` : `somevalue`. **key** and **value** are duplicate information for each object in the list.

After seeing more feedback from the comments IMO the best bet here would be to introduce a custom deserialized which will be used to convert the input JSON into a `Map<String, String>`. More about custom deserializers and example can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization).

Comment: It makes sense if you serialize map as map entries (meaning list of {key:k,value:v} objects)and not plain json object. Jackson can serialize JSON object into map, yes, but I am looking for inbuild way to deconstruct object into map. See my snippet (working)

Comment: `{"keyName":"keyValue","valueKey":"valueValue"} ` What is the benefit of having `keyName` and `valueKey` ? Isn't this duplicate information that will exist for every entry in the map?

Comment: Done, it should be clearer now for you.

Comment: @Antoniossss Updated the answer with what seems to be a viable solution for your case. I doubt that an annotation exists that can provide this solution for you out of the box, since this requirements seems weird at least and not expected behavior from an API